# How can I store the toggleClass of multiple selectors & their respective classes in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, local-storage

I'm trying to store the toggled class of multiple elements in local storage or cookies so that the toggled class stays upon refresh. I have tried js cookie & all the other tutorials on here but it doesn't seem to work with multiple selectors/divs.

Here's my code so far:

```
$('#one').on('click', function () {
    $("body").toggleClass("white-bg");
    $(".menu-link, .hello-text, .titles").toggleClass("blue");
    $("g#g-icon").toggleClass("g-icon-blue");
    $("#one").toggleClass("night");
});
```

The code functions perfectly, but doesn't save the state when I refresh.

Comment: just save all the toggled `classes` with keys as there `el` e.g. `{'menu-item':'classname',""}`, then `stringify` the object and save in localstorage. Then on page reload get this `item` and `parse` it using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Hey Abdul, thanks for your comment. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this, but it seems straightforward. Could you possibly show me how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to save on localStorage only "flag" with information if user changed theme or not (clicked or not).

For example:

```
var changed = localStorage.getItem('changed') === 'changed';
$('.selector').toggleClass('classname', changed);
```

Full primitive but working example: https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/y7bLpwxr/